# Trying to use functions

Tags: arcpy, function

Trying to use functions. First, embed the code in script, then I'll trying calling them from a file. I'm getting the error denoted below. After two days, it's time to get some fresh eyes ...

Python 2.7

**Error:**

```
  File "C:\Temp\Polylines.py", line 28, in addLine
    cursor.insertRow((name, polyline))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insertRow'
```

**Script:**

```
Import occupy

# Set up the Environment
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\Data" 

# Variables
desc = arcpy.Describe('Leases1.shp')
spatRef = desc.spatialReference
fc = 'WellPaths.shp'
inputFile = open(r"C:\Temp\WellPaths.txt")
outFolder = r"C:\TEmp\Data"
fieldList = ["Name","SHAPE@"]
name = ""
prev_name = ""

#Functions
def obtainCursor(outFolder, fc, spatRef):
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outFolder, fc, "POLYGON", "", "", "", spatRef)
    print "Created feature class ... "

def addLine(name, pointList, cursor):
    polyline = arcpy.Polygon(pointList)
    cursor.insertRow((name, polyline))
    print "Added " + name

cursor = obtainCursor(outFolder, fc, spatRef)

pointList = arcpy.Array()

for line in inputFile:
    ln = line.split(", ")
    name = ln[0]
    if name != prev_name: 
        if pointList.count > 0: 
            addLine(name, pointList, cursor)
        pointList = arcpy.Array()
        prev_name = name
        point = arcpy.Point(float(ln[1]), float(ln[2]))
        pointList.add(point)
    else:
        point = arcpy.Point(float(ln[1]), float(ln[2]))
        pointList.add(point)
# Last line  
addLine(name, pointList, cursor)

del cursor
```

Comment: What problems are you encountering? What would you like help with? Please update your post to include these items.

Comment: Your `obtainCursor` does not have a return statement (which implies `return None`) so you therefore assign `cursor = None` and hence you get an error doing `None.insertRow`.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to  specify the version of ArcGIS in use.  You left out cursor creation in obtainCursor, so it's hard to tell if you are using "old-style" cursors or best-practice DA cursors.

Comment: Updatedto denote Python 2.7.

Comment: What version of ***ArcGIS***?  It's the *arcpy* that matters more than the Python.

Comment: The ArcGIS version doesn't matter: the question is about Python syntax (using functions), and just so happens to be have some arcpy statements. It could be any module. I voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: It does matter, because the missing cursor creation syntax is different (10.0 and earlier don't support DA cursors)

Answer (score 1):

You define cursor as the output of the obtainCursor function, but that function does not appear to be returning anything.  So when you later call .insertRow, you are calling that on a null object, hence the error.

You can fix it by adding something like:

```
return arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc)
```

Comment: I added "return cursor" to the obtainCursor function. Is that what you are referring to?  Sorry, I'm new to Python.

Comment: I would recommend going to the Python documentation and Python stack overflow for help with writing functions